# undefined class QNetworkProxy using Qt 5.9.1 uwp x86 msvc2015

Tags: qt, uwp

I have a project (compilation ok x86 msvc2015) which I want to port to UWP but suddenly a compilation error undefined class appeared. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added `QT += network` to your pro file? Does _Rebuilding_ works (or clear build output before building)?

Comment: yes I have it there (it is a working project in win32), I tried rebuild project, nothing works

Comment: QNetworkProxy is known by QtCreator, and also by compiler somehow, because if I put there QNetworkProxy1 it gives me "unknown override specifier" instead of "using undefined class"

Comment: Do you use Desktop App Converter to convert your program to UWP?

Comment: no I just downloded qt uwp x86 so I can built it from sources